# Декораторы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Поясните, пожалуйста, следующее высказывание, желательно с примерами. Я новичок и никак не могу осилить эти декораторы.

> Декораторы могут быть использованы для расширения возможностей функций из сторонних библиотек (код которых мы не можем изменять).

Comment: Пропустите это высказывание и изучайте декораторы дальше, потом поймёте

Comment: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#a-few-real-world-examples

Comment: декаратор принимает функцию - модифицирует/дополняет её и возвращает новую функцию

Comment: Я так и не понял, как задекорировать функцию из стороннней библиотеки?

Comment: Передаете в функцию-декоратор функцию сторонней библиотеки, из декоратора получаете новую "улучшенную" функцию.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Предположим, что в душе вы настоящий римлянин и вам неудобны варварские цифры, которые использует Python. Есть способ преобразовывать варварские цифры в римские и обратно - модуль [roman](https://pypi.org/project/roman/). Но чтобы использовать его со стандартными функциями, такими как `min` и `max`, придётся писать код преобразований перед каждым вызовом. Типа:

```
min_number = toRoman(min(fromRoman('VII'), fromRoman('X')))
```

Неудобно и неблаговидно! Поможет декоратор:

```
from functools import wraps

def romanize(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return toRoman(f(tuple(fromRoman(i) for i in args), **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

Декорируем интересующие функции

```
min = romanize(min)
max = romanize(max)
```

И теперь в любом месте кода можем использовать их с римскими цифрами:

```
min_number = min('VII', 'X')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Bra1n [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).